# Why doesn't DirectX work in Visual Studio 2022 when using .NET Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0, directx

I have a dll that uses .NET Framework 4.0 and DirectX and works and debugs fine in Visual Studio 2019. When I ported over to VS2022 DirectX no longer worked and the dll wouldn't load. I had to change it to .NET Framework 3.5 to get DirectX to work but now I can't debug it.

I have tried everything I could find which was virtually nothing.

Comment: It should definitly work. How do you use DirectX from .NET Framework? Difficult to say more w/o more information.

Comment: The way it uses DirectX is it references Microsoft.DirectX, Direct3D, Direct3DX, DirectDraw, DirectSound. The code uses using Microsoft DirectX, Direct3D, DirectSound.  I have tried every framework up to 4.8 and the dll builds but won't load correctly. Again, it works fine in VS2019.

Comment: You can't "reference" DirectX from .NET just like that, so how you do it technically? Or post a minimal reproducing sample https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug a .NET Framework 3.5 dll in Visual Studio 2022. Symbols not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76475177/how-do-i-debug-a-net-framework-3-5-dll-in-visual-studio-2022-symbols-not-loadi)

Answer (score 1):

The `Microsoft.DirectX`, `Direct3DX`, `DirectDraw`, and `DirectSound` components are the legacy deprecated Managed DX 1.1 assemblies. They have not been updated since ~2006 and were written for .NET 1.1.

They work with .NET 2.0 Runtime, but do NOT support any newer .NET Runtime. The assemblies are only deployed using the legacy DirectX SDK or legacy *DirectX End User Runtime* installer package.

They are also ONLY available for 32-bit (x86). Therefore they do not work with x64 or AnyCPU.

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers)

> Starting with Visual Studio 2022, Visual Studio no longer includes .NET Framework components for .NET Framework 4.0 - 4.5.1 because these versions are no longer supported. Visual Studio 2022 and later versions can't build apps that target .NET Framework 4.0 through .NET Framework 4.5.1. To continue building these apps, you can use Visual Studio 2019 or an earlier version.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/).